# Website is untidy when resolution is resize

Tags: php, html, css

I made this website a week ago http://kaizer.xayo.net/home.php

and everytime I resize or try it onto the other computer the layout is untidy

I've been searching for my solution yesterday and can't still figure it out how to fix it.
I'm so sorry I know this is a basic problem I'm just new to css and html and php.

Comment: Check out bootstrap responsive templates like the ones at http://startbootstrap.com

Comment: Search on google for responsive design, lots and lots of people can explain how to create a website, which is made for different resolutions.

Comment: I will thank you for your replies.

Comment: Have a look at CSS media queries. When resizing down, and the design breaks you can add in a breakpoint, and style it differently.

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.  Please include the [relevant parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain in specific terms what you're trying to accomplish and how your results differ from the desired results (as opposed to vague subjective terms like "the layout is untidy"). Include any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [ask] and [Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is **responsive design**, Initially what you can do is use `%` in place of `px` and use `em` where `%` is not working.
Essentially you can use front-end design frameworks like **bootstrap** and **foundation** to build responsive design easily, however I will not recommend this to you as of now. Form what I have learned never automate your talk unless you are in tight deadline or you are a pro because as a beginner it is better to learn the core stuff the then move to automation to make things fast.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is **responsive design**. There are different ways to do that via HTML/CSS

For a start, read up on CSS media queries and then try out some established frameworks such as Bootstrap.

Here are some links:

1. [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)
2. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)